# Need the BDD table Format for Multiline text validation

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, bdd

Its the HTML DOM of the Actual Text:

[image]

BDD Table - I was passing like this:

[image]

Error:

[image]

I need to validate the Multi line text by passing the data through the table. Can anyone help me on this?   But at the same time, I shouldn't change the code in Step definition.

Comment: Please always provide a minimum reproducible work/code snippets in order to reproduce the error and thus provide you some way around to solve it. 

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example